# Access violation while reading location error when reading a 6 digit number

Tags: c++, int, runtime-error

I'm running to code bellow and get an access violation error when I input a number which has more than 5 characters. Im not sure what is wrong with the code, what do I have to change?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string Type(int no)
{
    cout << "this arrives: " << no;
    return ("this arrives: "+ no);
}

int main()
{
    int num; //ID input
    int i = 0;
    ifstream reader("TypeID.txt"); //File with ID names

    if (!reader) {
        cout << "Error opening input file" << endl;   //Display error
    }
    else {
        cout << "input TypeID number" << endl; //When sucsesful display user instructions
        while (true) //while the file has loaded run Type conversion
        {
            cout << "TypeId: "; //Prompt user to enter Type no
            cin >> num; //put input into int "num"

            while (num > 0) { //num greater than 0
                Type(num);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            } //as long as input is greater than 0 Type functio is run and Type name is returned
            cout << endl << "Next number for conversion" << endl;
        }
        return 2;
    };
}
```

If your running this code just use a dummy file for the TypeID.text file it is looking for as the code won't look for the contents yet.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: When it is run and after you input a 6 digit number it breaks. The source code has no errors.

Comment: The source code does have errors, otherwise it would work.  What I'm asking is; what line causes the crash?  (Hint: run it in a debugger.)

Comment: Here is an image of the line that is highlighted http://imgur.com/5VLxlzt
and the debugger says this "First-chance exception at 0x00B18051 in TypeID to Name.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00B7B728."

Comment: The `break`-statement in you inner `while`-loop only stops that single loop, making the outer `while`-loop and infinite one.

Comment: I want the outer while loop to go infinite as this is more of a module I'm making for a larger program.

Comment: So you want the user to enter numbers for ever in your larger program?

Comment: I'm only moving the function over to the larger program, but that isn't really implemented yet (and I'm already having issues :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression,

```
("this arrives: "+ no);
```

is pointer arithmetic. A pointer to the first character of the literal is moved `no` number of places in memory. In the outer context the resulting pointer is used to construct a `std::string`, which use has **Undefined Behavior** if `no` is greater than 14 or so.

For what you probably intended, do

```
"this arrives: "+ to_string( no );
```

There's also much else that could be fixed and/or improved, but start with the above.

---

To avoid `<stdafx.h>`, ***turn off*** use of precompiled headers in your Visual Studio project settings.

Comment: I know that there is a lot to add, I guess that this is more of a prototype than a 'proper program'. I changed the return value to:
    return("main");
as I didn't need to return the number and it hasn't had any more problems